# NSFileManager read files from server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager

Is it possible to load and handle files from a distant server via NSFileManger?

```
fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:@"https ...
```

Connect via URLConnection to authenticate at the server.

If this ist not possible, what would be the best way to read directory contents and download the files?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP has no concept of directories only files, the simplest way to read a file synchronously trough HTTP is NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error: e.g.:

```
NSString *robots = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",robots);
```

Here is a example for ftp:

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData  *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/misc/webrick-cve-2010-0541.diff"]] returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if(data == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}else{
    NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"got %@",str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it now and it doesn't work.

NSFileManager can't access files on Server with http: ...

It will produce CocoaError 262 = NSFileReadUnsupportedSchemeError.